# how implement a gRPC/Proto endpoint with repeated in message (i.e nested types in request and response)

Tags: kotlin, protocol-buffers, grpc, micronaut, grpc-java

Goal: I want to code a microservice exposing an endpoint receiving and responding a message with repeated. I tried apply what I learned from [Proto official guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#nested) and I coded this proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.mybank.endpoint";
option java_outer_classname = "TransactionsProto";
option objc_class_prefix = "HLW";

package com.mybank.endpoint;

import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

service TransactionsService {
  rpc PostTransactions(TransactionsRequest) returns (TransactionsReply);
}

message TransactionsRequest {
  string transactionDesc = 1;
  repeated Transaction transactions = 2;
}
message Transaction {
  string id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  string description = 3;
}

message TransactionsReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

I could gradle build and I got this TransactionsServiceGrpcKt autogenerated

```
package com.mybank.endpoint

import com.mybank.endpoint.TransactionsServiceGrpc.getServiceDescriptor
import io.grpc.CallOptions
import io.grpc.CallOptions.DEFAULT
import io.grpc.Channel
import io.grpc.Metadata
import io.grpc.MethodDescriptor
import io.grpc.ServerServiceDefinition
import io.grpc.ServerServiceDefinition.builder
import io.grpc.ServiceDescriptor
import io.grpc.Status.UNIMPLEMENTED
import io.grpc.StatusException
import io.grpc.kotlin.AbstractCoroutineServerImpl
import io.grpc.kotlin.AbstractCoroutineStub
import io.grpc.kotlin.ClientCalls.unaryRpc
import io.grpc.kotlin.ServerCalls.unaryServerMethodDefinition
import io.grpc.kotlin.StubFor
import kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext
import kotlin.coroutines.EmptyCoroutineContext
import kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads
import kotlin.jvm.JvmStatic

/**
 * Holder for Kotlin coroutine-based client and server APIs for
 * com.mybank.endpoint.TransactionsService.
 */
object TransactionsServiceGrpcKt {
  @JvmStatic
  val serviceDescriptor: ServiceDescriptor
    get() = TransactionsServiceGrpc.getServiceDescriptor()

  val postTransactionsMethod: MethodDescriptor<TransactionsRequest, TransactionsReply>
    @JvmStatic
    get() = TransactionsServiceGrpc.getPostTransactionsMethod()

  /**
   * A stub for issuing RPCs to a(n) com.mybank.endpoint.TransactionsService service as suspending
   * coroutines.
   */
  @StubFor(TransactionsServiceGrpc::class)
  class TransactionsServiceCoroutineStub @JvmOverloads constructor(
    channel: Channel,
    callOptions: CallOptions = DEFAULT
  ) : AbstractCoroutineStub<TransactionsServiceCoroutineStub>(channel, callOptions) {
    override fun build(channel: Channel, callOptions: CallOptions): TransactionsServiceCoroutineStub
        = TransactionsServiceCoroutineStub(channel, callOptions)

    /**
     * Executes this RPC and returns the response message, suspending until the RPC completes
     * with [`Status.OK`][io.grpc.Status].  If the RPC completes with another status, a
     * corresponding
     * [StatusException] is thrown.  If this coroutine is cancelled, the RPC is also cancelled
     * with the corresponding exception as a cause.
     *
     * @param request The request message to send to the server.
     *
     * @return The single response from the server.
     */
    suspend fun postTransactions(request: TransactionsRequest): TransactionsReply = unaryRpc(
      channel,
      TransactionsServiceGrpc.getPostTransactionsMethod(),
      request,
      callOptions,
      Metadata()
    )}

  /**
   * Skeletal implementation of the com.mybank.endpoint.TransactionsService service based on Kotlin
   * coroutines.
   */
  abstract class TransactionsServiceCoroutineImplBase(
    coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext
  ) : AbstractCoroutineServerImpl(coroutineContext) {
    /**
     * Returns the response to an RPC for com.mybank.endpoint.TransactionsService.PostTransactions.
     *
     * If this method fails with a [StatusException], the RPC will fail with the corresponding
     * [io.grpc.Status].  If this method fails with a [java.util.concurrent.CancellationException],
     * the RPC will fail
     * with status `Status.CANCELLED`.  If this method fails for any other reason, the RPC will
     * fail with `Status.UNKNOWN` with the exception as a cause.
     *
     * @param request The request from the client.
     */
    open suspend fun postTransactions(request: TransactionsRequest): TransactionsReply = throw
        StatusException(UNIMPLEMENTED.withDescription("Method com.mybank.endpoint.TransactionsService.PostTransactions is unimplemented"))

    final override fun bindService(): ServerServiceDefinition = builder(getServiceDescriptor())
      .addMethod(unaryServerMethodDefinition(
      context = this.context,
      descriptor = TransactionsServiceGrpc.getPostTransactionsMethod(),
      implementation = ::postTransactions
    )).build()
  }
}
```

So far so good. Now I want to implement it and I am completed stuck.

Here is all three tentatives and its errors

```
package com.mybank.endpoint

import io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class TransactionsEndpoint : TransactionsServiceGrpc.TransactionsServiceImplBase(){

    //First tentative
    //This complains "'postTransactions' overrides nothing" and IntelliJ suggest second next approach
    //override fun postTransactions(request: TransactionsRequest?) : TransactionsReply {

    //Second Tentative
//    override fun postTransactions(request: TransactionsRequest?, responseObserver: StreamObserver<TransactionsReply>?) {
//        //it complains Type mismatch... Found: TransactionsReply
//        return TransactionsReply.newBuilder().setMessage("teste").build()
//    }

    //Third Tentative
    //This causes:
    //Return type is 'TransactionsReply', which is not a subtype of overridden public open
    // fun postTransactions(request: TransactionsRequest!, responseObserver: StreamObserver<TransactionsReply!>!):
    // Unit defined in com.mybank.endpoint.TransactionsServiceGrpc.TransactionsServiceImplBase
    //override fun postTransactions(request: TransactionsRequest?, responseObserver: StreamObserver<TransactionsReply>?) : TransactionsReply {
//        return TransactionsReply.newBuilder().setMessage("teste").build()
//    }
}
```

gradle.build

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.3.72"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "1.3.72"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen" version "1.3.72"
    id "application"
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.13'
}

version "0.2"
group "account-control"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    // for dependencies that are needed for development only
    developmentOnly
}

dependencies {
    kapt(enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"))
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java")
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")

    implementation(enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinxCoroutinesVersion")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
//    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-server-runtime:$micronautGrpcVersion")
    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-client-runtime:$micronautGrpcVersion")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub:${grpcKotlinVersion}")

    //Kafka
    implementation("io.micronaut.kafka:micronaut-kafka")

    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.8")

    kaptTest("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java")

    testImplementation enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.0")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.22.0")

    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.0")
    testRuntime("org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:1.1.5")
}

test.classpath += configurations.developmentOnly

mainClassName = "account-control.Application"

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

allOpen {
    annotation("io.micronaut.aop.Around")
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11' 
        //Will retain parameter names for Java reflection
        javaParameters = true 
    }
}
//compileKotlin.dependsOn(generateProto)

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11' 
        javaParameters = true 
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    classpath += configurations.developmentOnly
    jvmArgs('-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1', '-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote')
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpckt'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protocVersion}" }
    plugins {
        grpc { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}" }
        grpckt { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:${grpcKotlinVersion}" }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
            grpckt {}
        }
    }
}
```

I have successfully created my first grpc endpoint with very basic request/reply based on String and now I want to move forward by creating a list of a message. As an analogy, let's say I want a DTO/Pojo which contains a list of an entity.

Honestly, I am totally stuck. So, my main question is: how implement a proto service with repeated message?

An useful comment that can give a north is, why I see in autogenerated stub a method to be implemented with "..., responseObserver: StreamObserver?" instead of a simple "TransactionsReply" as I clearly specify in my proto? What relationship between StreamObserver and repeated message?

Here is the whole project [in my GitHub develop branch](https://github.com/jimisdrpc/account-control.git)

You will find two protos: one well successful implement with simple request/reply and other failing as explained above.

*** edited after first answer from Louis

[image: after removed suspend]

I am quite confused.
With a simple proto as

```
...
service Account {
  rpc SendDebit (DebitRequest) returns (DebitReply) {}
}

message DebitRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message DebitReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

I can implemented with

```
override suspend fun sendDebit(request: DebitRequest): DebitReply {
    return DebitReply.newBuilder().setMessage("teste").build()
}
```

Nevertheless, with

```
...
service TransactionsService {
  rpc PostTransactions(TransactionsRequest) returns (TransactionsReply);
}

message TransactionsRequest {
  string transactionDesc = 1;
  repeated Transaction transactions = 2;
}
message Transaction {
  string id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  string description = 3;
}

message TransactionsReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

I can't override with same type of response (note that the reply is exactly the same)

neither this implementation proposed from IntelliJ

```
override fun postTransactions(request: TransactionsRequest?, responseObserver: StreamObserver<TransactionsReply>?) {
        super.postTransactions(request, responseObserver)
        return TransactionsReply.newBuilder().setMessage("testReply").build()
    }
```

nor this with similar response approach

```
override fun postTransactions(request: TransactionsRequest?, responseObserver: StreamObserver<TransactionsReply>?) :TransactionsReply {
    super.postTransactions(request, responseObserver)
    return TransactionsReply.newBuilder().setMessage("testReply").build()
}
```

On top of that, why if the reply is exactly the same, in my first approach I didn't get StreamObserver proposed from IntelliJ?

*** Final solution thanks to Louis' help. I extended wrong abstract class

```
override suspend fun postTransactions(request: TransactionsRequest): TransactionsReply {
    return TransactionsReply.newBuilder().setMessage("testReply").build()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for

```
class TransactionsEndpoint : TransactionsServiceGrpcKt.TransactionsServiceCoroutineImplBase(){
   override suspend fun postTransactions(request: TransactionsRequest) : TransactionsReply {
      ...
   }
}
```

...with the `suspend` modifier and no `?` on the request, extending `TransactionsServiceCoroutineImplBase` with the `Coroutine` in there.

Note that this has nothing to do with a repeated message.  Your RPC has a *single* input proto, which gets sent only once -- which may well be what you want, unless you want a *stream* of requests, in which case your proto file should look like

```
service TransactionsService {
  rpc PostTransactions(stream TransactionsRequest) returns (TransactionsReply);
}
```

...and the Kotlin generated code will look different in that case.

Comment: Louis, thanks. It is easy to see you know what I am doing wrong but I couldn't fix it yet. I am not interested in return a stream (not this time). I just want to code my first enpoint returning a nested object as we tipicaly do with dto in Rest. I removed supsend since I I understand it is not my case. I just learned that "... suspending functions can only be invoked by another suspending function or within a coroutine...". I tried the above approach (see my edited answer) with no succes

Comment: I don't understand why with a very simple Proto containing request and reply with single String I implemented succesfully with "override suspend fun sendDebit(request: DebitRequest): DebitReply { return DebitReply.newBuilder().setMessage("teste").build()" but just because I changed the request but keep the reply identical I can't implement the response equally. Well, certainly it changes the request but I would expected the response be the same.

Comment: The gRPC framework is invoking your method.  Leave `suspend` on there, but you don't have to implement it any differently or do anything that suspends.  But can you post the exact code you tried with `postTransactions`, with the `suspend` version?  Did you make sure you were extending the correct `ImplBase` class, with `Coroutine` in it?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the issue: I was extending "TransactionsServiceGrpc.TransactionsServiceImplBase" and the correct should be "TransactionsServiceGrpcKt.TransactionsServiceCoroutineImplBase". Today is exactly one month I have been studing Micronaut+GRPC+Proto+Kotlin and I have a loooot to learn.